# Composing a sequence of functions of variable types in scala

Tags: scala, types, higher-order-functions, function-composition

What I'm trying to do is apply a sequence of transformations to a dataset where each function takes the output of the previous step and transforms it for the next step. E.g.

```
val f1: Function1[Int, Double] = _ / 2d
val f2: Function1[Double, BigDecimal] = x=>BigDecimal(x - 2.1)
val f3: Function1[BigDecimal, String] = _.toString

val chained = (f1 andThen f2 andThen f3)(_)

println(chained(10))
```

What I want is a function f that takes an input a Seq(f1, f2, ...) and returns the chaining of them, where f1, f2, ...fn do not all have the same input and the same output types T. But they are composable, so for example:

```
f1: Function1[A,B]
f2: Function1[B,C]
f3: Function1[C,D]
```

then the chaining function will return a function 
    f: [A,D].

Thanks,
Z

Comment: Could you please clarify the question

Comment: what is not clear exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solution proposals here:

1. A solution that requires a special kind of list that can keep track of all the types in the chain of functions.
2. An `asInstanceOf`-heavy solution which works on ordinary lists.

---

**Keeping track of all the types of intermediate results**

An ordinary list would lose track of the types of all the intermediate results. Here is a list of functions that keeps track of all those types:

```
sealed trait Func1List[-In, +Res] {
  def ::[I, O <: In](h: I => O): Func1List[I, Res] = ConsFunc1(h, this)
}
object Func1List {
  def last[In, Res](f: In => Res): Func1List[In, Res] = LastFunc1(f)
  def nil[A]: Func1List[A, A] = LastFunc1(identity)
}

case class LastFunc1[-In, +Res](f: In => Res) 
  extends Func1List[In, Res]
case class ConsFunc1[-In, Out, +Res](head: In => Out, tail: Func1List[Out, Res]) 
  extends Func1List[In, Res]
```

Now, for a `Func1List`, we can define a function that concatenates all the elements:

```
def andThenAll[A, Z](fs: Func1List[A, Z]): A => Z = fs match {
  case LastFunc1(f) => f
  case c: ConsFunc1[A, t, Z] => c.head andThen andThenAll[t, Z](c.tail)
}
```

A little test:

```
val f1: Function1[Int, Double] = _ / 2d
val f2: Function1[Double, BigDecimal] = x => BigDecimal(x - 2.1)
val f3: Function1[BigDecimal, String] = _.toString

val fs = f1 :: f2 :: Func1List.last(f3)
val f = andThenAll(fs)

println(f(42)) // prints 18.9
```

---

**Just `asInstanceOf` all the things**

A somewhat less refined, but much shorter solution:

```
def andThenAll[X, Y](fs: List[_ => _]): X => Y = fs match {
  case Nil => (identity[X] _).asInstanceOf[X => Y]
  case List(f) => f.asInstanceOf[X => Y]
  case hd :: tl => hd match {
    case f: Function1[X @unchecked, o] => f andThen andThenAll[o, Y](tl)
  }
}
```

This here also results in `18.9`:

```
println(andThenAll[Int, String](List(f1, f2, f3))(42))
```

Comment: @ZoharEtzioni There should be no difference in performance whatsoever. At the runtime, all the types are erased anyway, and you are left with exactly the same function composition. The difference between the two solutions is visible only at compile time, because the first solution does a somewhat better job of guaranteeing that all the types fit together as expected.

Comment: you're right in that the former approach will not compile if the I/O don't fit, and the latter will fail in runtime. I like it! thanks.